# Cannot Generate ParameterSetMetadata While Programmatically Creating A Parameter Block

Tags: powershell, metaprogramming, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to programmatically create a parameter block for a function ( along the lines of [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/01/04/extending-and-or-modifing-commands-with-proxies.aspx) ).

I'm starting with a [CommandMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.commandmetadata.ctor(VS.85).aspx) object (from an existing function).  I can create the [ParameterMetadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.parametermetadata(VS.85).aspx) object and set things like the ParameterType, the name, as well as some attributes.

The problem I'm running into is that when I use the [GetParamBlock method of the ProxyCommand class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.proxycommand(VS.85).aspx), none of my attributes that I set in the Attributes collection of the ParameterMetadata are generated.

The problem this causes is that when the GetParamBlock is called, the new parameter is not annotated with the appropriate Parameter attribute.

Example:

```
function test 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    [Parameter()]
    $InitialParameter)

    Write-Host "I don't matter."
}

$MetaData = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData (get-command test)

$NewParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata 'NewParameter'

$NewParameter.ParameterType = [string[]]

$Attribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute 
$Attribute.Position = 1
$Attribute.Mandatory = $true
$Attribute.ValueFromPipeline = $true

$NewParameter.Attributes.Add($Attribute)
$MetaData.Parameters.Add('NewParameter', $NewParameter)


[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetParamBlock($MetaData)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function test 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    [Parameter()]
    $InitialParameter)

    Write-Host "I don't matter."
}

$MetaData = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetaData (get-command test)

$NewParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata 'NewParameter'

$NewParameter.ParameterType = [string[]]

$Attribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute 
$Attribute.Position = 1
$Attribute.Mandatory = $true
$Attribute.ValueFromPipeline = $true

$NewParameter.Attributes.Add($Attribute)
$MetaData.Parameters.Add('NewParameter', $NewParameter)

$ParameterSetMetadata = "System.Management.Automation.ParameterSetMetadata"
$ParameterSetInfo = new-object psobject -Property @{ 
    Position=[Int]::MinValue
    Flags=3
    HelpMessage="Please Enter a Value"
} | ForEach { 
    $_.PSTypeNames.Add("Deserialized.$ParameterSetMetadata")
    write-Output $_ 
}

$converter = new-object  Microsoft.PowerShell.DeserializingTypeConverter
$ConvertedSet = $converter.ConvertFrom($ParameterSetInfo,$ParameterSetMetadata, $null, $true)

$NewParameter.ParameterSets.Add('__AllParameterSets', $ConvertedSet )

[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetParamBlock($MetaData)
```

Comment: First off, thanks for the answer, however using 'OutVariable' to copy the parameter set info from throws an error - 

Cannot index into a null array.
At line:25 char:55
+     $MetaData.Parameters['OutVariable'].ParameterSets[ <<<< '__AllParameterSets'] )
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (__AllParameterSets:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

If I try using my previous parameter, I get different information in the attribute property and the parameter set property.  The information from the parameter set property is what script is generated.

Comment: Yeah, you can't alter the parameter set, or else it changes the place you got it from. Forget that, try this new reflection method. I can't believe there's no way to create that class.

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised that there wasn't a constructor for that.  Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: @jaykul, yeah, i wasted about 45 minutes on this - i came to the same conclusion but wasn't willing to accept that reflection is the answer so I didn't go that route. I still can't believe it.

Comment: Since x0n couldn't figure it out, that provided the extra motivation for me to dig up the sanitized route to that method.  This new code actually does the conversion using the same internal static method I was using before, but via a public method (albeit via a slick hack of a custom PSObject I couldn't have known to create without reflection).

Comment: Good job Jaykul - I love the Deserialized hack.

Comment: Jaykul, I have problem right where I think the issue is in relation to deserialisation. Your answer above is closest I've come to getting a solution. Would you mind take a look please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554807/powershell-passing-objects-to-to-start-job

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does not show up is because your NewParameter needs to belong to at least one parameter set. In this case, it should be a member of the special parameterset, "__AllParameterSets."

You can verify this by copying the ParameterSetMetadata instance from InitialParameter. Unfortuntely I can't see immediately how to get this ParameterSetMetadata if you don't have any parameters to grab it from. Copying it from the other parameter makes it appear in the output, but it's the metadata from InitialParameter, so this is not the solution, only the reason why it doesn't work (yet.) I'll update this post when I figure it out.

-Oisin

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I can copy the metadata from an existing parameter, but that just seems wrong, especially since you can then have a discrepancy between the attributes property and the parameter sets property. ;(

Comment: yeah, it's not the right way at all. sorry if that didn't come across clearly.

Answer (score 0):

rant on:
I was even very, very angry that we can instantiate a Type of System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata but we cannot initialisize it.
Microsoft destroys much joy of the class library by contraining the classes by use of private or internal or sealed...... they use it to often, and without any thinkable reason.
That is a very nuts library design!
rant off:

For metaprogramming and to create ProxyCommands (proxy functions) I had the need to create a Windows PowerShell Parameter programatically from scratch.
I even dont like to break into classes and steal and use vorbidden stuff, that is subject to change. Even the serialization trick is the same dirty way to do the same on a different route.

here is my prototype of a solution.
I am creating a Function with a Parameter as Text (function sourcecode).
my first atempt was to do a New-Item Function:\ -value {code} into the function drive and then do a Get-Command to the new function to extract the Metadata. But this shows up, that the function was a dead sorcecode only horse. It was not got compiled.
So I had to use Invoke-Expression to 'compile' the sourcecode of the function.

```
Function New-Parameter {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Switch]$Mandatory,
        [UInt32]$Position,
        [Switch]$ValueFromPipeline,
        [Switch]$ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName,
        [Switch]$ValueFromRemainingArguments,
        [String]$HelpMessage,

        [Type]$Type=[Type]'System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter',
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$Name,
        [String]$DefaultValue,

        [Switch]$DontShow,

        [String[]]$ParameterSetName,
        [String[]]$Aliases,
        # if Metadata is present the result is an System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata object
        # If Metadata is absent the sourcecode for the Parameter is returned
        [Switch]$Metadata
    )

    $ParameterAttrib = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

    # using GUID to create an unique function Name
    $Guid = ([Guid]::NewGuid()).ToString()

    # using a StringBuilder to glue the sourcecode 
    $stringBuilder = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder

        If($Metadata.IsPresent) {

        # Open the Function{} block
        [Void]$stringBuilder.AppendLine("Function $Guid {")

        # add the [CmdletBinding()] attribute 
        [Void]$stringBuilder.AppendLine("[CmdletBinding()]")

        # Open the Param() block
        [Void]$stringBuilder.AppendLine("param(")
    } 

    # query if we have one or more ParameterSetName
    $ParmameterSetNameCount = 0
    If(-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($ParameterSetName)) {
        $ParmameterSetNameCount = @($ParameterSetName).Count
    } 

    # Open the [Parameter()] attribut
    [Void]$stringBuilder.Append('[Parameter(')

    If($Mandatory.IsPresent) {
        [Void]$ParameterAttrib.Add('Mandatory=$True')
    }
    If($Position) {
        [Void]$ParameterAttrib.Add("Position=$Position")
    }
    If($ParmameterSetNameCount -gt 0){
            # in the first full blown [Parameter()] attribut allways insert the first ParametersetName
            [Void]$ParameterAttrib.Add("ParameterSetName='$($ParameterSetName[0])'")  
    }


    If($ValueFromPipeline.IsPresent) {
        [Void]$ParameterAttrib.Add('ValueFromPipeline=$True')
    }
    If($ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName.IsPresent) {
        [Void]$ParameterAttrib.Add('ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True')
    }
    If($ValueFromRemainingArguments.IsPresent) {
        [Void]$ParameterAttrib.Add('ValueFromRemainingArguments=$True')
    }
    If($DontShow.IsPresent) {
        If($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 4) {
            Write-Warning "The 'DontShow' attribute requires PowerShell 4.0 or above! `n Supressing the 'DontShow' attribute!"
        } Else {
            [Void]$ParameterAttrib.Add('DontShow')
        }

    }
    If(-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($HelpMessage)) {
        [Void]$ParameterAttrib.Add("HelpMessage='$HelpMessage'")
    }

    # generate comma separated list from array
    [Void]$stringBuilder.Append("$($ParameterAttrib -Join ',')")

    $ParameterAttrib.Clear()

    # close the [Parameter()] attribut
    [Void]$stringBuilder.AppendLine(")]")
    $ParmameterSetLoopCounter++

    # If we have more then one ParametersetName
    IF($ParmameterSetNameCount -gt 1) {
        # add remaining parameterset names the parameter belongs to
        for ($i = 1; $i -lt $ParmameterSetNameCount; $i++) { 
            [Void]$stringBuilder.AppendLine("[Parameter(ParameterSetName='$($ParameterSetName[$i])')]")  
        }  
    }

    # Create Alias Attribute from Aliases
    If(-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Aliases)) {
        [Void]$stringBuilder.AppendLine("[Alias('$($Aliases -join "','")')]")
    }

    # add Parameter Type
    [Void]$stringBuilder.Append("[$($Type.Fullname)]")

    # add the Parameter Name
    [Void]$stringBuilder.Append("`$$Name")

        If(-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($ParameterSetName)) {
        [Void]$stringBuilder.Append("=$DefaultValue")
        }

    If($Metadata.IsPresent) {
        # close the Param() block
        [Void]$stringBuilder.AppendLine()
        [Void]$stringBuilder.AppendLine(')')

        # close the Function block
        [Void]$stringBuilder.AppendLine('}')
    }

    # return the result
    If($Metadata.IsPresent) {
        # if we have to return a ParameterMetadata Object we create a temporary function
        # because you can instatiate a ParameterMetadata Object but most of the Properties are constrained to get only and not to set!

        # Create and 'compile' the function into the function: drive
        Invoke-Expression ($stringBuilder.ToString())

        # from the temporary function we query the the ParameterMetadata and
        # return theParameterMetadata Object
        (Get-Command -Name $Guid -CommandType Function).Parameters.$Name

        # remove the Function from Function: drive
        $Null = Remove-Item Function:\$Guid -Force

    } Else {
        # return the sourcecode of the Parameter
        Write-Output $stringBuilder.ToString()
    }

}

#Example calls:

# without Parametersets
New-Parameter -Name 'Param1' -Mandatory -Position 3 -ValueFromPipeline -ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName -ValueFromRemainingArguments -HelpMessage "Give me hope Joana!" -Type 'System.String' -Aliases 'Ali1','Ali2','Ali3' -DontShow -DefaultValue 34
New-Parameter -Name 'Param1' -Mandatory -Position 3 -ValueFromPipeline -ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName -ValueFromRemainingArguments -HelpMessage "Give me hope Joana!" -Type 'System.String' -Aliases 'Ali1','Ali2','Ali3' -DontShow -DefaultValue 34 -Metadata

# with Parametersets
New-Parameter -Name 'Param1' -Mandatory -Position 3 -ValueFromPipeline -ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName -ValueFromRemainingArguments -HelpMessage "Give me hope Joana!" -Type 'System.String' -ParameterSetName 'Snover','Payette' -Aliases 'Ali1','Ali2','Ali3' -DontShow -DefaultValue 34
New-Parameter -Name 'Param1' -Mandatory -Position 3 -ValueFromPipeline -ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName -ValueFromRemainingArguments -HelpMessage "Give me hope Joana!" -Type 'System.String' -ParameterSetName 'Snover','Payette' -Aliases 'Ali1','Ali2','Ali3' -DontShow -DefaultValue 34 -Metadata
```

**AM I DOING RIGHT TO CONSTRUCT THE PARAMETERSETS?**