# PowerShell - Passing OBJECTS to start-job - deserialize

Tags: powershell, scope, arguments, deserialization

I know that a script block executed via start-job cannot see the variables outside of the script block. To pass variables in you use the `-arguments` paramater. From the doco I've read though, jobs can't pass objects to each other without [serialising](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs?view=powershell-7.1) them. Apparently this is because of how jobs works - when using `Start-job`, PowerShell creates a new process and runs the commands there; in order to transfer the object to the other process it needs to serialise it, then the other exe will deserialise it when it gets imported. This poses a problem when you want to use objects with start-job.

**NOTE**: The below are examples to demonstrate my problem - the actual cmdlets and scripts I am running are completely different and more complex, so in case you are wondering why I would even run these commands this way just bear in mind I wouldn't, they are just easy commands to demonstrate my issue.

Here is an example of the syntax I've used for a simple Get-aduser command

```
$user = get-aduser samaccount
```

When we output $user we see that the object is of type `ADUser`

```
$user|GM
TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser
```

Let's now serialise the object (to simulate what start-job does)

```
$user| Export-Clixml C:\temp\test.xml
```

And now rebuild it (deserialise)

```
$user = Import-Clixml C:\temp\test.xml
```

Now when when we view it's type it is different. It has the word 'derserialzed' in front.

```
 $user|GM
TypeName: Deserialized.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser
```

The problem I now have is that it isn't a true representation of the orignal object. Even if all the properties and settings were identical we still have the problem that the object type is different. Now to demonstrate why this is a problem.

`Get-aduser` accepts a string as the input (very first example) but it also will accept a valid `ADuser` object. But when we now run:

```
get-aduser $user
```

We get the following error:

```
"Cannot convert the "AD_distinguishedname_here. I have omitted this for security reasons" value of type 
"Deserialized.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser" to type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser"."
```

This error is because Get-aduser expects you to provide an object of type `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser` but we provided `Deserialized.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser`and it doesn't know how to convert it. This is exactly what happens when you run command via start-job and why you can't pass objects to a job.

As I said above, I am not using get-aduser in my real code, I am just using this simple command everyone has access to, to demonstrate the issue. In my real code I ***must*** provide an object to the job.

So my question is, does anyone know how you get around this or know how to rebuild the object in it's original form?

Comment: What you heard about `-ArgumentList` is incorrect.  You can absolutely pass objects in using this method.  "Arguments must be passed to ArgumentList as single-dimension array argument. For example, a comma-separated list."  This just means that you should not pass in a hashtable of parameter/argument pairs.  Instead just pass your arguments in order of the parameters listed in your scriptblock param() block or if not using a param() block access your arguments using the $args array.

Comment: Well it still doesn't work, I tried it. I've done some more reading since. I think it's because of the serialisation/deserialisation I mention above. According to MS article here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.1#serialization-of-variable-values it says that backound jobs (start-job) get serialised then deserialised. If you look at my error above it states that the object type is "deserialised". I tihnk this is the issue. How do convert it back to the original object type?

Comment: As for your question, AD cmdlets are notoriously finicky.  That error is not cause by passing in the object to Start-Job or Invoke-Command, it's caused by the way Get-ADUser returns slimmed down (deserialized) objects with only minimal properties or the properties you request.  I usually end up have to do things like `Get-ADUser $user.SamAccountName` instead of just `Get-ADUser $user`.  This is problem directly, not only in background jobs.

Comment: No it is...Read the article, it specifically states that is the reason. get-aduser by itself does not return derserialised data. The issue (it seems) is that the data gets written to disk temporarily (so the other process can pick it up), this is known as "serialisation". The background job reads it from the file and reconstructs it, but it's not a true copy, so its type is set to deserialised.

Comment: `Get-ADUser` outputs an [`ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com//powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser#outputs)  **object**. `Start-Job` [serializes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)  the (`$user`) object provided by the `-InputObject` parameter (this usually happens in memory). As stated in your own referral: ["For complex types, the copy is imperfect"](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables#serialization-of-variable-values).

Comment: As `Get-ADUser` uses a deferred execution ([lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation), it retrieves the information at the moment you actually access one of its properties), it only serializes the top level which can't be deserialized across the process boundary. As suggested by [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954025/daniel), simply use: `-InputObject $user.SamAccountName` to share the identity of the user between the processes.

Comment: Both of you are correct in that passing the samaccount name will work, but as I said in my question I am using get-aduser as an example - the real code I am using requires the input to be an object. So if I can get it working in the above I can translate this to the real code I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending 8 hours on this straight I finally figured out what is going on. It's a long story but thr TLDR version is that you cannot get around this with any native tools - you have to essentially rebuild the object inside the start-job script block, and if you have a large complex object this just isn't feasible. I ended up findind a module you can download which runs commands via start-thread instead of the start-job and this does not use serialisation. [Guide here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_thread_jobs?view=powershell-7.1) to DL and install it. This worked when I tested it

To get the PowerShell module, go to PowerShell gallery and search for "start-thread"

Comment: Ha! I'm glad you found that. I just now saw your comment on another thread. I guess I don't StackOverflow enough. 

My answer really was going to be: have you tried PSThreadJob. 

Comment: yep, thanks. you did some great work btw on that other thread creating your own deserialisation method!

Comment: Thank you. this saved my ass. i was trying to pass a HttpClient and it always de/serializes